# Applying style to argument of spring message

Tags: html, css, spring

I am using `<spring:message ... arguments="${arg1},${arg2}" />` Is it possible to add html code with css style for each argument?

For example we want to print the message and have the first argument bold and blue and the second argument red.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. Its not clear what you want. an image could help.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add code quotes. I fixed the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by just adding html code inside the argument element (it seems the HTML code is executed and not just written as text):

```
<spring:message code="label.pay.message" arguments="<strong><span class='currency'>${lastInvoiceAmountIntPart}</span>;<span class='sup-currency-decimals'>${lastInvoiceAmountDecimalPart}</span></strong>" argumentSeparator=";"/>
```

This is not quite readable but it works fine.